# Is there any way to internally store long-ish term data in an Apps Script project?

Tags: google-apps-script, data-storage

Is there any way to store data in an Apps Script project for any long-ish amount of time without creating a new file from scratch? I couldn't find any real way searching around, but the biggest stumbling block is that I don't want to have to embed it into a spreadsheet with an `onOpen()` method in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of way to hold onto data in a script project. The main places would be:

**ScriptDB** - a NoSQL DB that is specific to your script project. This in my prefered method for storing data associated with a script. [ScriptDB Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/script-db/)

**Script and User Properties** - Cross project properties that are specific to the script or to the user. Useful for storing information you as the script writer has no business knowing. [See More...](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)

You can also make connections to [external SQL databases](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) and there is a [short-term caching service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/) that can be used as well.

Comment: I knew about script properties, but I didn't want to rely on those (considering they were already being used for different purposes). Which would be better in terms of speed?

Comment: I believe that ScriptDB is fastest, but occasionally I run into API access frequency problems and need to add a `Utilities.sleep` to avoid abusing the service.